# Transferring an old DotNetNuke site

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to help a client move an old DotNetNuke site to a new host (old one shutting down)

The DNN site runs version 3.2 (according to right-click > Details > Product Version on the DotNetNuke.dll).

I'm having a hard time find info on this old version.

What version of ASP.NET does this need?

New host has .NET 2 & 4. Any chance this can be setup on a .NET 2 machine?

Is there anywhere where I can get a hold of the original manuals for this? (DNN site only goes back to version 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general process of moving a site is:

- Copy all the files in the website folder to new server
- Backup and restore the database on the new server
- Configure IIS for the new site
- Edit connection string in web.config for new sql server credentials

You can find some docs that shipped with the release at http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/19992.

I also noticed that the 3.x line requires .Net1.1, the 4.x line uses .Net2.  That was way before my involvement with DNN.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any config manual for DNN 3.2? I've done all the step and configured it for .Net 2 environment but DNN isn't liking it

Answer (score 1):

3.2 Runs on 1.1.  I have had some success with doing this on 2.0, but it will depend on the modules.  More than likely though, you want it on 1.1.